# JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, php, json

i am trying to return json encoded array to a div from PHP. i receive JSON.parse: unexpected character. any help is appreciated.

Query

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var acct =$('#acct').val();

  $.getJSON("CJS/jsontest.php",{acct: acct}, function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
  });

});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  include_once '../Functions/dbconnect.php';


$varacctname = $_REQUEST['acct'];
$varViewContacts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE c_company = '$varacctname'");

$rows = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($varViewContacts)) {

    $rows[] = $row;

  }
echo json_encode($rows);
```

MY JSON

```
[{"c_ID":"21","c_FirstName":"Mike","c_LastName":"Be","c_Phone":"123456789","c_ext":"0","c_fax":"0","c_address1":"","c_address2":"","c_city":"","c_state":"","c_zip":"0","c_country":"Account","c_Email":"mike.be@test.com","c_Mobile":"123456789","c_company":"TEST"}]
```

Comment: what happens if you do the load the results directly in the browser? `http://example.com/jsontest.php?acct=1`

Comment: Do you have a closing `?>` tag for your PHP file? Does the console log what the unexpected character is?

Comment: You're going to have to look at the output.  We cannot guess what your code does.

Comment: @JoePasq There is absolutely no need for a closing `?>` PHP tag in a file that is purely PHP.  In fact, I suggest that is best practice to not include it, to avoid stray whitespace from making it into places it shouldn't.

Comment: I get the correct info if i load from the browser directly.

Comment: @BEBO Show us that output.

Comment: [{"c_ID":"21","c_FirstName":"Mike","c_LastName":"Be","c_Phone":"123456789","c_ext":"0","c_fax":"0","c_address1":"","c_address2":"","c_city":"","c_state":"","c_zip":"0","c_country":"Account","c_Email":"mike.be@test.com","c_Mobile":"123456789","c_company":"Test"}]

Comment: @JoePasq I do have the closing tags.. sorry didn't copy it.

Comment: @Brad that’s neat Brad, I did not know that, thanks.

Comment: You sure you don't have quotes printing out at the beginning and ending of the data coming outta PHP?

Comment: @user602525 No, my code is exactly what you see above..:)

Comment: I have no idea why, but your json is invalid. I can't get it to pass through a validator

Comment: @BEBO There are unprintable characters in the last element of your JSON.

Comment: @BEBO can you paste that json elsewhere? Edit your question? Or wrap `like this`? Because there are some weird characters.

Comment: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ run it through there and you will see them

Comment: I added the JSOn output to the question. @user602525 i validated and it looks fine.

Comment: When I validate it, it fails on three different sites, unless SO is adding weird characters to it.

Comment: Thats Weird. Try this [link]http://jsonblob.com/52abe8dae4b058a62f0ec1cf

Comment: We cannot really help you if you/we are not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling I simple want the returned data to show in the (#result) on the page. Firebug shows the correct reponse, but not the page. also i get JSON.parse: unexpected character on the firebug script tab.

Comment: @user602525 - Copy/pasting the JSON from the question into jsonlint.com gives me a "valid" result.

Comment: Yea, I get invalid on every site I try. But as others have pointed out, it is valid, so, no idea what is going on on my end, but I withdrew my answer because of it.

Comment: So i hit the wall on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the content type anywhere in your PHP code before you send the data. I don't see it in your example.

You should have:
header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: Tried it.. same results. If it helps i get the error on line 4 jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

I have run a simple test with your code and it works fine for me. Here is the code.

```
var JSON = '[{"c_ID":"21","c_FirstName":"Mike","c_LastName":"Be","c_Phone":"123456789","c_ext":"0","c_fax":"0","c_address1":"","c_address2":"","c_city":"","c_state":"","c_zip":"0","c_country":"Account","c_Email":"mike.be@test.com","c_Mobile":"123456789","c_company":"TEST"}]';

var parsed = $.parseJSON(JSON);

console.log(parsed);
```

**I am using latest version of JQuery and it interprets your JSON the right way.**

So in my opnion **$.getJSON()** method is not able to recognize the incoming JSON. If you get your data as text and then parse it by **$.parseJSON()** (don't forget to include JQuery's latest version in your project), it might work for you. Kindly try it and then let me know, I will change the code accordingly.

Comment: And yes another problem can be that your PHP code is not sending proper JSON so that means Jquery is not able to recognize the incoming data as proper JSON and $.getJSON() method fails

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand, the JSON seems to be valid.

Comment: Yes actually sometimes the problem is that we are not receiving proper JSON headers, this means that "$.getJSON()" is expecting JSON but it does not fin proper headers or something that tells it that incoming data is JSON. So a good way is to receive it as text and parse it once received. In that regard you will use $.ajax() and tell it to expect text. Once received, parse the data by $.parseJSON()

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to send dummy data such as (adjust as needed - you get the idea):

```
echo json_encode(array(array('name' => 'Joe')));
```

If that works then I would suspect some character encoding issue coming out of the database and start looking at utf8 converter functions (they abound [online](http://www.php.net/json_encode) for php json encoding issues). The browser console might be sterilizing things which might explain why it works directly.

If it doesn't work then I would make a single php page with just the echo line above to ensure that nothing else was sent (and don't add a closing php tag - safer that way)

I would also investigate your php version - some have issues with blank strings from what I understand. You could upgrade or try using the alternative json_encode functions that were made for earlier php versions such as [this](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html) one.

Comment: I would agree on sending the dummy data, but don't you think that the JSON coming is correct and it is just a matter that it is not being recognized properly. Maybe the headers sent are wrong. Getting this JSON as text and then parsing it can help in my opinion.

Comment: I would agree yes but one of the things about json_encode that people don't realize is that it's not meant to return valid json data necessarily - it only meant to convert array structures into the json format. I have had to make so many escape functions when dealing with this. My approach is more of trying to eliminate each issue one at the time. He says he tried the json headers above so not sure what else. A bit of a shot in the dark :)

Comment: Yes I agree, but after testing the JSON in editor and by $.parseJSON() I am quite convinced that the JSON returned is accurate and the only problem is in the interpretation, anyhow lets hope that @BEBO gets the proper idea.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird, but when recreated the PHP file the problem seems to went away.. not sure but i think it has to do something with editing with NotePad++ .. The second time i created the file with Submlime text and it was fine. so it could be encoding issue.. Thanks everyone for their input.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get invalid JSON string response. I just solve the similar issue this morning. And I desided to check(try/catch) the ajax response string(if it can be parsed) first instead of a direct calling of JSON property(it's jsonRes.result in my case). So try to put the following code into your AJAX complete callback function:

```
    complete: function(data) {
        var jsonRes = null;
        try {
            jsonRes = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        }
        catch(e) {
            jAlert('Invalid JSON object);
        }
        if (jsonRes===null || jsonRes.result===undefined) {
            jAlert('Invalid Ajax response structure');
        }
    }
```